# Which is the signature of the matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $A\in \mathbb{R}^{4\times 4}$ is a real symmetric matrix with characteristic polynomial $$\chi_A(x)=x^4-9x^3+cx^2+dx+37$$ If we know that all eigenvalues of $A$ have the same sign , which is the signature of the matrix $A$ ?

The signature is number of positive eigenvalues minus number of negative eigenvalues.

So is the signature either $4$ or $-4$, since the characteristic polynomial  is of degree $4$ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the eigenvalues $\lambda_1,\lambda_2,\lambda_3,\lambda_4$ of $A$ are the roots of the characteristic polynomial, we have $$\chi_A(x) = x^4-9x^3+cx^2+dx+37 = (x-\lambda_1)(x-\lambda_2)(x-\lambda_3)(x-\lambda_4).$$ By comparing the $x^3$ coefficient of both sides, we get $\lambda_1+\lambda_2+\lambda_3+\lambda_4 = 9$. By comparing the constant term of both sides, we get $\lambda_1\lambda_2\lambda_3\lambda_4 = 37$.

We are given that all the eigenvalues have the same sign. Since $\lambda_1\lambda_2\lambda_3\lambda_4 = 37 > 0$, none of the eigenvalues can be zero. If all the eigenvalues were negative, we'd have $9 = \lambda_1+\lambda_2+\lambda_3+\lambda_4 < 0$, a contradiction. Hence, all the eigenvalues must be positive, i.e. the signature of $A$ is $4-0 = 4$.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer!! :-)